# 'Cannis' - Term used in seventeenth-century clothes manufacture

Tags: meaning

My local history group is transcribing a series of account books kept by the overseers of the poor in Woodchurch, a village in the English county of Kent. One of the transcribers has come across these two entries:

- Item paid John Prior for butons teap and cannis and makinge a coate for Widdow Hills boye
- Item pocketts tape and cannis for the waste bond and to skins

The word we are struggling to find a meaning for is 'cannis'. It looks as though it could be a plural of an item used in tailoring. Online searches of the OED and Google haven't produced any obvious solutions. Seventeenth-century spelling is notoriously phonetic, so the term could be 'cannes' or 'cans' or any similar-sounding variant. If there is anyone here familiar with historical clothing terms, we would love to hear from you.

Comment: Perhaps is it canna, a measure of cloth? See the OED. (Also spelled cane).

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, Laurel. That is certainly a possibility we've considered, but the OED puts this definition firmly in Italy, southern Europe and the eastern Mediterranean -- a world away from our community of farmers and agricultural labourers. Of course, one of our overseers could have been well travelled, in which case this could be the right meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the product is ***canvas***.

For example, see: *[THE LIVING AGE VOLUME CXCV](https://books.google.com/books?id=16IxAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=%2B%22cannis%22&pg=PA527#v=onepage&q=%20%22cannis%22&f=false)*, Publisher, Littell, Son and Company, 1892, Contributors Eliakim Littell, Robert S. Littell, Making of America Project:

[image: quote from THE LIVING AGE VOLUME CXCV]

Transcribed:

> Coarse linen was woven by the village weaver into *harn* for shirts and bed-coverlets. The latter was ***cannis*** or canvas (Lat. *canabis*, hemp). A similar sheet was laid down to receive the grain when it was being threshed, hence the Buchan proverb, "We can thres i' oor ain **cannis**".

That is, you've heard of *cannabis*, marijuana, and its relation to the plan *hemp*, a textile.  The textile is canvas.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I thought when I read the question  ..but I couldn’t  find evidence to support it.

Comment: @Dan Bron Many thanks indeed for pointing us at 'canvas'. Embarrassingly, an obvious candidate that we simply failed to spot. Going back to the OED, the entry for 'canvas' lists several 17th century dialect forms including 'cannas' and 'canness' that correspond neatly to the spelling variants used by our overseer.